# If $G$ is a finite group and $H \subset G$ is closed, must $H$ be a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Supposed theorem (from online notes): If $(G,*)$ is a finite group and $H\subset G$, $H$ is non-empty and $H$ is closed under $*$ then $(H,*)$ is a group.

The proof given is a real mess, but, after many dead ends it seems to me that the inverse of every element of H should also be in $H$. Is that true?

I have $x\in H$, $e\in H$ and $x*x^{-1}=e$ where $e$ is the identity element in $G$. I think I need to have $x^{-1} \in H$.

Comment: The proof probably goes somewhat like this. Let $x\in H$, and consider the powers $x,x^2,x^3,\dots$. By assumption these are all in $H$. By finiteness there exist $i\lt j$ such that $x^i=x^j$. Then $x^{j-i}=e$, so $e$ is in $H$. Let $e=x^k$. Then $(x)(x^{k-1})=e$, so $x^{k-1}$ is the inverse of $x$, and $x^{k-1}$ is in $H$.

Comment: Note that you need only $H$ to be finite, not $G$. If a $H$ is a finite, non-empty subset of $G$ closed under $*$, then it is a subgroup of $G$. The case where $H$ is a subset of a finite group $G$ is then an obvious special case.

Answer (score 5):

It is true: By taking repeated powers $x, x^2, x^3, ...$ of an element $x \in H$, we eventually must have a repeat $x = x^n$ for some $n>1$ (why?). This implies that $x^{n - 1} = e$ and that $x^{-1} = x^{n - 2}$, so $H$ is closed under inverses as well as products.

Comment: Why indeed? All we can say is that $x^k = x^l$, for some $k < l$. We don't know (yet) that it cycles right back to the first element. We only know there's a cycle *somewhere* in the sequence (thus making the sequence finite). But the rest of the proof is very similar.

Comment: Well, the existence of *any* cycle easily implies that the cycle hits $x^1$ too.

Comment: Yes, once you note that $x^k = x^l \implies x^{l - k} = e$. But it's not a more direct implication, is it? I mean, if we didn't have inverses (if this were a semigroup, for example), we might very well have cycles which never come back to $x$ (or $e$).

Comment: Example: Take the monoid of real $n \times n$ matrices under multiplication, and let $x$ be a nilpotent matrix. Then $x^n = 0$ (zero matrix) for some $n$, and then all higher powers would be $0$ too, but none will be equal to $x$.

Comment: This was explicitly assumed to be a group....

Comment: Oh yes, but my point is that without using inverses, it's not possible to conclude $x^n = x$. When we directly say that we must have a repeat, and therefore, $x = x^n$ for some $n > 1$, it hides a part of the reasoning (the part where inverses are used). Written that way, it looks like it'd work just as well in a semigroup, but it doesn't. I gave the semigroup example just to show that something non-obvious is missing in the statement.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple proof that only requires $H$ to be finite (and non empty).

For $x\in H$, consider the map $f_x\colon H\to H$ defined by $f_x(h)=x*h$. This map is injective (prove it), so it is surjective because $H$ is finite. Then there exists $h_0\in H$ such that 
$$x=f_x(h_0)=x*h_0=x;$$
therefore $h_0=e$ and so $e\in H$. But then we have also $h_1\in H$ such that
$$
e=f_x(h_1)=x*h_1
$$
and so $h_1=x^{-1}\in H$. Since $x\in H$ was arbitrary, we have proved that $e\in H$ and $x^{-1}\in H$, for all $x\in H$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lvert G \rvert = n < \infty$ we have
$x^{n} = e$. Hence $x^{-1} = x^{n-1}$, which is obviously in $H$.

Comment: It's actually $x^n=e$, not $x^{n-1}$.

Comment: You meant $x^n=e$ surely? While this is a valid argument this kind of *subgroup criteria* often come before Lagrange's theorem (which is what your proof is relying on).